# JavaScript loop inside tinymce button

Tags: javascript, arrays, tinymce

My JavaScript loop is not working properly inside a tinymce button.

I set a variable n which is the array size that I get from my html input.

```
var n = $('#total').val();
```

Then, I create the array of tinymce buttons: `var menuItems = [];`

In my tinymce editor init, I create the buttons:

```
editor.on('init', function (e) {

        for (var i=1; i<=n; i++){
            var obj = {
                text: 'Item ' + i,
                onclick: function() {
                    var msg = '&nbsp;<strong>#item' + i + '#</strong>&nbsp;';
                    editor.insertContent(msg);
                }
            }
            menuItems.push(obj);
        }
    });
```

Last step is add the menuItems to the tinymce buttons:

```
editor.addButton('myButton', {
        type: 'menubutton',
        text: 'Items',
        icon: false,
        menu: menuItems 
    });
```

The buttons are displaying correct with the correct label. I have the buttons:

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3

However, doesn't matter which button I click, the text displayed in the editor is item3. It always get the last button text. 
Does anyone know why it is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var` since `let` would keep its **lexical block scope** where `var` would not:

```
editor.on('init', function(e) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  // <-- use let here
    var obj = {
      text: 'Item ' + i,
      onclick: function() {
        var msg = '&nbsp;<strong>#item' + i + '#</strong>&nbsp;';
        editor.insertContent(msg);
      }
    }
    menuItems.push(obj);
  }
});
```

Here is the [documentation on let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)